# Proving that a poset can be expressed as a union of subchains.

Tags: order-theory

Let $L$ be a finite partially ordered set where the maximum size of an antichain is $n$. I need to prove that $L$ can be expressed as a union of $n$ subchains.

Here is my attempt:

$L$ must have at least $n$ elements. If it has $n$ elements then it is the union of each of these elements (which individually form chains). If it has $n + 1$ elements we can take $n$ elements which cannot be compared and make them each into their own chain. Take the left over element which must be able to be compared with at least one more element and add it to that element's chain.

Proceed by induction. If $n+k$ elements can be made into $n$ subchains we must show that $n+k+1$ elements must can be made into $n$ subchains. Because there are more than $n$ elements, there must be at least one "maximal element" (or "minimal element", similarly defined) which is greater than every element it can be compared to and that can be compared to at least one element. Remove this element. Fit the $n+k$ left over elements into $n$ chains and then the "maximal element" can be placed at the top of one of the $n$ chains.

Is my proof correct? If (and only if) my proof is correct, I am interested in knowing how this result can be extended to infinite partially ordered sets. My book mentions that it is possible with "transfinite methods" but has not described what these are.

If my proof is not correct, what is missing?

Gratis.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is incorrect. The problem is that you aren't guaranteed to be able to fit element $n+k+1$ into any of the existing chains. As an example, consider the set $\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, ordered by divisibility:

```
4   6
 \ / \
  2   3   5
```

The maximum size of an antichain in this set is $3$. Suppose we build $3$ chains $2-6$, $3$, and $5$. We can't fit $4$ into any of these chains, so the induction fails.

---

The question has been edited several times in a way that invalidates existing answers. I'm leaving this up in a state that answers the original question, but it may no longer address the question's current state.

Comment: Should I try and modify my inductive proof or use a noninductive method?

Comment: @bof: I tried to come up with an example like that, but I didn't think of anything. I've replaced the example with yours, as yours is much better.

Comment: @user162369: The proof I know works by induction. Try splitting the set along the antichain into "upper" and "lower" pieces.

Comment: I have modified my proof. @bof I have not heard of any of those things but I will look them up.

Comment: @user162369: Sorry, misremembered the proof. I've looked it up now, so the new hint should work better. I'm afraid your modified proof doesn't work, and bof's poset is a counterexample.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the hint? I assume I am supposed to begin with the $n$ element antichain and build off of that.

Comment: @user162369: Try building two smaller sets, one with all elements higher than the antichain removed and one with all elements lower removed, and try to apply the inductive hypothesis to those sets. The case where one of these subsets is the whole set has to be handled separately.

Comment: Can it be that an element is higher than one element of the antichain but lower than another?

Comment: @user162369: No, because then those two elements of the antichain would be comparable.

Comment: The proposition you're trying to prove is called Dilworth's theorem. The proof given on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem) is kind of like what you were trying to do, i.e., you start by removing a maximal element, and decomposing the remaining set into chains. However, you can't just add the new element to one of those chains, some kind of rearrangement is involved.

Comment: Have I started the proof correctly? I just need to prove the special case. @bof Thank you for the link.

Comment: @user162369: StackExchange isn't designed for this kind of interaction; it's based on an ask-question-get-answer interaction model, not extended conversations. Edits like the kind you're making invalidate existing answers. If you want someone to check your work and keep checking it as you modify it, you could try the chat.

Comment: @user162369: That said, you seem to be on the right track. A more rigorous statement of why you can join the chains along the antichain is necessary, though.

Comment: ok I will delete the question